# Placing div side by side make height full page

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to achieve the attached design.  Basically, I have a top bar in the page, which has a few buttons on left, and few on right.
Below the top-bar, I have another section (Div), which has two buttons placed side by side.

For the top bar, I combined the two buttons on left in a single div, and two buttons on right in another div, made these two divs as float left and right respectively. Given I had wrapped them in another div, I expected the second section to start from next line onwards, but in the end they are all coming in a single line, i.e.

"top-bar (left stuff)" "2nd section button1" "2nd section button2"  "top-bar (right stuff)"

Why is my second section not starting from the next line onwards?

```
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="bar-left">
    <span class="top-bar-title text">MYTEXT</span>
    <img src="res/rev.svg" alt="MY Logo"/>
  </div>
  <div class="bar-right">
    <a href="www.google.com">About</a>
    <button class="login-btn">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="two-btns">
  <button class="btn1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="btn2">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

And CSS is

```
.bar-left {
    vertical-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.bar-right {
    vertical-align: center;
    float: right;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem are the floats on the `bar-left` and `bar-right` elements.
When you give `float` to an element it "remove the element from the document's flow", so it is kind of like your top-bar is empty (and collapses) because both children have floats.

My suggestion would be to use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` on the top-bar element and remove the floats from the `bar-left` and `bar-right` elements.

I made a JSFiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/gc02r59p/

You can read here about the [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) property and here about the [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) property

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.two-btns {
  clear: both;
}
```